# How do I smooth a loop in a Bezier curve?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

I'm trying to animate a jet flying a loop by having it follow the path of an animated Bezier curve. The problem is that each time the jet passes over a vertex in the curve it pitches just a bit as though it's running over a bump, which is unrealistic. Is there a way to smooth the loop so the jet flies more smoothly?

I've tried everything I can think of, including applying Smooth from the Bezier context menu, but that just makes the loop smaller, and manually tweaking the vertices can make the bumps less noticeable, but they are still there. Thanks. Blender 3.5.1, Windows 11

[Blend file example](https://www.arcadiastreet.com/share/how_to_smooth_bezier_curve_debug2.blend)

Comment: Hello, could you please tell at what frame it is particularly noticeable?

Comment: 200 and 240. I replaced the jet with a cube in the linked example, and it is not quite as noticeable with the cube. Thanks.

Comment: Don't you need to scale up or down some of the vertices (like scale down the vertex that is before the one the object reaches at frame 200)?

Comment: I did not know you can scale the vertices. I am new to this curve stuff. :)

Comment: so do you get what you want with a bit of tweaking?

Comment: I'll have to play with it. Sometimes the issue seems obvious, other times not so. I've seen a lot of air shows so I want to get this reasonably right. Thanks again for your help! :)